# Build a SQL query with a DateTime parameter

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I can successfully use a Query with a Date parameter in string format as

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE [DATE]='20160209'
```

but I haven't seen any sample of a Query specifying a DateTime parameter in string format.
Next samples are rejected by Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE [DATE]='20130523T153500000Z'
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE [DATE]='2013-05-23T15:35:00:000Z'
```

I know this is not a good practice and I should pass DateTime values rather than strings, but sometimes it is useful for debugging.

What is the right format to include a string formatted datetime on a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No so sure where you've got those date formats... 
This one '2013-05-23T15:35:00:000Z' just doesn't seem to be right. I haven't seen that nanoseconds were delimited by a ':' character. It is usually a decimal of a second, so '2013-05-23T15:35:00.000Z' is a better format and it works:

```
select convert(DateTime,'2013-05-23T15:35:00.000Z')
```

As for the other, you might need to do the parsing yourself:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT('20130523T153500000Z',4)+SUBSTRING('20130523T153500000Z',5,2)+SUBSTRING('20130523T153500000Z',7,2))
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE [DATE] = CONVERT(DATETIME,'20130523T153500000Z')
```

As long as the string is in a workable format.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for debugging, you might do something like:

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(25)

-- Easily swapped out with different testing values
SET @val = '20130523T153500000Z'

SELECT * 
FROM Orders
WHERE [DATE] = CAST(@val AS DATETIME)
-- You could also use CONVERT
```